# Maintain a connection while switching server in port-forward ssh session (Golang)

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am connecting to an API server endpoint through a bastion host using ssh port-forwarding with some Go code.

The simplified version of the code goes like this:

```golang
func handleTransfer(local net.Conn, remote net.Conn) {
    defer local.Close()
    defer remote.Close()
    done := make(chan struct{}, 2)

    // Start remote -> local data transfer
    go func() {
        for {
            _, err := io.Copy(local, remote)
            if err != nil {
                // do something
            }
        }
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    // Start local -> remote data transfer
    go func() {
        for {
            _, err := io.Copy(remote, local)
            if err != nil {
               // do something
            }
        }
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()
    <-done
}

func tunnelThroughBastion() {
    //create a local listener
    localListener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:6443")
    defer localListener.Close()
    
    // Get sshConfig
    sshConfig, _ := createSshClientConfig(username, config.SshPrivateKeyFile)

    // Dial the Bastion host via SSH
    sshConn, _ = ssh.Dial("tcp", bastionAddr, &sshConfig)
    defer sshConn.Close()

    // Enter listen loop
    for {
        // accept local connections
        local, _ := localListener.Accept()
        // dial remote server using ssh connection
        remote, _ = sshConn.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6443")
        // handle data transfer in both directions until connection closes
        handleTransfer(local, remote)
    }
}

func main() {
    // for the sake of keeping it simple, it runs forever like this:
    for {
       tunnelThroughBastion()
    }
}
```

The issue: my bastion host has a timeout setting that I cannot extend, so every so often, the bastion is terminated and needs to be re-created.

I have more code handling the detection of the bastion session terminating (actually looking at when it will terminate and preemptively creating a new one) so as to update the `sshConfig` etc... and I can redial the `sshConn`, and on a new accepted connection, the code proceeds as needed seamlessly, re-dialing over the new SSH tunnel and transferring data again.

However, issues arise when the connection is in progress when the disruption happens, for example, when pulling logs continuously from the API server.

With a long polling request, the response is a stream of data, so when the SSH connection terminates, the `handleTransfer` part of the code errors, but the connection is already closed by then.

I would like to understand how I could keep the stream going despite disruption.

Since I am copying data to transfer from the local to the remote connection, and similarly I am transferring from the remote to the local connection, when the io.Copy errors, I thought I might be able to redial the remote at that point and continue streaming, but when I tried that, client connection had already been closed before the io.Copy error even showed up.

It seems to me, the client is the one making the connection, and then waiting for a response. The response being a stream, it keeps receiving data, but if that response is disrupted because the remote connection is closed, there is no easy way to recreate that response stream without first re-sending the original request. Is that a correct assessment? If so, how could I capture that and 'retry' that request somehow?

The end goal is to avoid disrupting the client, and keep the log stream coming in without having to re-run the command. Any insight on how this could be achieved would be appreciated.